# npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile-application

I want to make an OTP verification page where

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.66.0
```

when I run `npm install react-native-otp-verify --save` it didn't run and faced an error which is given in attatched file.

[image]

After the above error, I have run `npm install react-native-otp-verify --force` but there is also an error and that is, **force protection is disabled** and the error is given below attached file,

[image]

**Note:** How should I solve it please concern about my problems! Advanced thanks!

Comment: Tried installing react-native 0.63? Sometimes, removing node modules and reinstalling using npm I also solves such errors

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
npm config set force false
```